# works on win10 but i get error on mac 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

```
import csv

with open('name_of_file.csv', 'r') as file:
    data_from_file = csv.DictReader(file)

    for i in data_from_file: #error in this line
        print(i)

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

So I did a small program on my pc that takes the values of each year in the csv file and then does some statistic calculations with those values. Now I want to add some new stuff to my code but in the meantime, I switched from windows to mac and I keep getting an error in the for loop. I just can't figure out what is wrong. I tested the code on other machines and this works. It's probably some rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried This:

```
for i in data_from_file.items(): #error in this line
        print(i)
```

Comment: nop :( (AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'item') not even .reader works as it should. because when I print i with an index it should return me the value at that index but I get an error. I am wondering if I am missing a package or something. i am no pro at this :\

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I meant dict().items() @MarinM